# Remove child tags/elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

i have a few milons rows of xml. There are the same parent tag, but more then one child tags, one of them child tags have a value which is *. My question is, how can i remove all of parents tags where the child tag contains * Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Could you provide a simplified version of the layout? For example: is this a single big file, or is this a collection of small XML documents in an XML-based document store?

Comment: Hi, its only one big xml file (225MB) if it helps, here is the structure.. <temp>...
  <change/>
 </temp>
 <temp>
  ....
  <change>*</change>
 </temp>

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple app if you know how to use XPath.. It is based on [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sf.net). The XPath I used is  /root/comment[change='*'].

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;
public class XPathRemove {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws VTDException, IOException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String inputXML = "<root><comment><change/></comment><comment><change>*</change></comment></root>";
        VTDGen vg= new VTDGen();
        vg.setDoc(inputXML.getBytes());
        vg.parse(false);
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        AutoPilot ap= new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/root/comment[change='*']");
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            xm.remove(); // remove all the selected comment node
        }
        xm.output("d:\\xml\\XPathRemove.xml");
    }

}
```